# Is it possible to sync just ONE file with lsyncd?

Tags: macos, synchronization, rsync

I really am stumped - I've spent almost two hours searching for an answer to a ridiculously simple question: how can I continually keep two local files in sync on my mac? I investigated various tricks involving `rsync`, then settled on using `lsyncd`.

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how I can get `lsyncd` to sync two specific files. Is this even supported in the API? It was not clear in the documentation whether or not I could use `rsync` in this manner; I assume that `lsyncd` is passing CLI options which are preventing this. My configuration is as follows:

```
sync = {
    default.rsync,
    source = "/Users/username/Downloads/test1.txt",
    target = "/Users/username/Downloads/test2.txt",
    rsync = {
        binary = "/usr/local/bin/rsync",
        archive = "true"
    }
}
```

It just says 'nothing to sync'. Help?

Answer (score 4):

This had worked for me:

```
sync {
    default.rsync,
    source = "/Users/username/Downloads/",
    target = "/Users/username/Downloads/",
    rsync = {
      binary = "/usr/bin/rsync",
      archive = "true",
      _extra = {
        "--include=test1.txt",
        "--exclude=*"
      }
    }
}
```

You have to use the include/exclude feature of lsyncd, which did not come out of the box. You have to use **_extra** field to set them.

Answer (score 1):

In lsynd you can do like this

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd-status.log",
    statusInterval = 20,
    nodaemon = true
}
sync {
   default.rsync,
   source="/srcdir/",
   target="/dstdir/",
   rsync = {
     archive = true,
     compress = true,
     whole_file = false,
     _extra = { "--include=asterisk", "--exclude=*" },
     verbose = true
   },
   delay=5,
   log=all,
}
```

After start lsyncd i have next

```
root@localhost:/srcdir# ls
12  aster  asterisk

root@localhost:/dstdir# ls
asterisk
```